# Is it possible to see questions tagged with ONLY the tag(s) I specify?

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to see if it is possible to see questions tagged with *only* the tag(s) I specify *and no others*?

Lets say, I want to be able see new questions with only the `[c#]` tag only and no others.  I just want to see questions with that single `[c#]` tag.  I don't want to see question tagged with say, `[c#]` *and* `[asp.net]`

Is this possible?

In a similar question I found the following suggestion but it does not work for me:

"You can build a bookmarlet using 'or'. Here is an example which shows the questions tagged 'C' along with the questions tagged 'C++':

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/'c'%20or%20'c++'"
```

The problem is this provides others tags also.

Comment: Using one of the above suggested answers I type  '*[C#]' but I don't get anything back.

Comment: @SNash That is a proposed feature, not an actual existing solution. The answer is that an exclusive search is not currently possible.

Comment: Not sure why , but none of above suggestions work for me.

Based on above [C#] -[ASP.NET] should only filter ASP.net out but I get 0 results.

Comment: @Bart , OK lets put this as an answer, It is good to know that currently there is no way to do this.

Comment: I must say above both similar questions are quite confusing as people seem to suggest there are ways to do this. –

Comment: @SNash as Bart said, please note the tags.  Both duplicates are feature requests asking for this feature because there is no way to do it and the "solutions" are either possible workarounds or proposed implementation of the feature.

Comment: @SNash [C#] -[ASP.NET] does work, I just tried it and got 411K+ results.  Are you sure you searched in SO and not MSO?

Comment: @ psubsee2003, Did you just banned me ? I cannot understand why asking this question sholud get me banned,even if you think this is duplicate. Before asking this question I did study several answers and could not find the answer.

Comment: @Bsubsee2003 , If you read my question you should see that i was not looking for [C#] -[ASP.NET] which provides many tags.

Comment: Yes I did search, and I do not think threatening new users with ban is the best way to invite more new users and promote SO.

Comment: @SNash I didn't ban anyone (nor do I have the power).  And yes I know what you were looking for, but you still seemed confused by the duplicates so I was attempting to clear up your confusion.  I was only responding to the fact that you said that [C#] -[ASP.NET] returns 0 results.

Comment: @ psubsee2003, well you did threaten me with ban in other post and interestingly I was banned right after your comment. I did not not get any downvotes(yet) for this question and my last question was a 8+ vote. WHY in the world in should get banned!!!????

Comment: Any question or answer bans happen fully automatically. This does not involve moderators and certainly not regular users. If you are banned from asking further questions on SO, it's because the majority has been downvoted, and all of them were closed as duplicates. Therefore the system has determined that you should not be asking questions until you've redeemed yourself. It's an automatic process and all you can do is follow the advice given to you in the ban message.

Comment: @SNash You can choose to believe what you want, but my comment in your earlier question was only inform you that one does exist, and this one was simple to try to help.  If you were banned right after my comment, it was only a coincidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search `[c#]` and you'll be redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23, which provides only the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag.

You can exclude specific tags by using the `-` operator, for example  [`[c#]-[asp.net]-[mysql]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#+-asp.net+-mysql)

Comment: I use the above but results are more than just C#.

I also get linq,Asp.Net, mysql

Comment: @SNash there probably aren't any

Comment: @SNash I just ran a data.SE query, there aren't any. However, see edit^^

Comment: If I run  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 
I get tons of unrelated tags including C++

Comment: @SNash no, those are feature requests. And I understood your question, however I'm saying that there _aren't_ any posts that are tagged with _only_ C#

Comment: @ Manishearth , how can you be sure that there aren't any posts that are tagged with only C#?

Comment: forgive my lack of knowledge but what do you mean by data.SE query?

Comment: I think currently I have to work with  [tag1]-[tag2]-[tag3]-...

as my only option.

Comment: @SNash I wrote an SQL query on http://data.stackexchange.com and checked.